# Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:10.2.5

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio for SMS verification for my Android app, but when I add the repository of Twilio verification dependency(**compile 'com.twilio: verification:+'**) the Gradle can not be built and shows the following error:
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:10.2.5
can anyone help me!

[image]

and I installed and update the repositories.[image]

**note:** for the first time it let me update the repository but now it doesn't let me update the repository.

Comment: click `install Repository`

Comment: have you install google play services from sdk manager

Comment: yes, I have already install repository, and this problem appears just when I add the Twilio verification (compile 'com.twilio: verification:+')  dependency.             @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @abdulkhaliqseddiqi can i get documentations for `com.twilio: verification:+'`

Comment: sure .https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide/integrating-twilio-verification-sdk-using-sample-backend#step-3-add-twilio-verification-sdk-for-android

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya . the dependency for Gradle that need is **com.twilio: verification:+'**

Comment: did you set `jcenter() ` ??

Comment: Actually, I don't' really know how to use Jcenter().but the only think that I am doing is that I adding **com.twilio: verification:+'** to build.gradle(Module: app) on dependencies block, do you think that I need to do more?

Comment: @abdulkhaliqseddiqi show your App level `build.gradle`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147152/discussion-between-abdulkhaliq-seddiqi-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same Problem with me, but i solved this problem by adding:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add that repository in your repository list. In your app’s <kbd>build.gradle</kbd>

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()  // This is missing 

    }
}
```

Comment: this allprojects block is allocated in build.Gradle(Project :myAppName)

Comment: still, it doesn't help me