# What is Twilio's SMS verification gradle dependency?

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-php

I am using Twilio for SMS verification to my android app using Android Studio, and I found this Dependency from Twilio official documentation(compile 'com.twilio: verification:+'), here is the link:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide/integrating-twilio-verification-sdk-using-sample-backend#step-3-add-twilio-verification-sdk-for-android

but as add this dependency, the Gradle shows error and can not be built, here I have already asked my answer:
[Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:10.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647943/errorfailed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-auth-api-phone10)

Is there anyone who knows what is the exact dependency of Twilio Verification to add in my Android Studio to use Twilio SMS verification.

Comment: Have you added `jcenter()` to the `allprojects { repositories { } }` object?

Comment: actually, I don't how to add it, can you help me how should I add this?

Comment: what do you mean by adding jcenter() @philnash

Comment: It looks like, from [your discussion here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147152/discussion-between-abdulkhaliq-seddiqi-and-intellij-amiya) that you've added jcenter to your build.gradle. Are you still seeing the same error?

Comment: Sure, there is the same error could you help me?

Comment: If you remove the Twilio dependency again, does Gradle build?

Comment: Yes, it builds so well, as I told you before, this problem shows while I am adding the Twilio Dependency. what do you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147260/discussion-between-abdulkhaliq-seddiqi-and-philnash).

Comment: @philnash do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any more. I've pointed my Android knowledgable colleague at this question and hopefully he can help.

Comment: @philnash thank you very much, are you Twilio employee? , and I am looking forward to your partner help

Comment: Yes, I work for Twilio. :)

Comment: Oh, I have forgotten to tell you, that I have already found my solution.

Comment: Oh fantastic! It might help if you share it as the answer to this question, in case other people have the same problem.

Comment: ok, I will, but you should give me an upvote.

Comment: @philnash I was just kidding, of course, I will share it, I was confused with this problem 3 days, and I don't want anyone else waste her, his time.

Comment: Heh :D That's cool, I'm glad you want to share and I apologise that I couldn't help you with this myself.

Comment: No, you did what you could Tnx again for your time if you want I am so eager that have you in my social media friends list.

Comment: You can find all the social links on [my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash?tab=profile) :)

Comment: TNX, I really appreciate your sharing, but unfortunately, I don't have Twitter or GitHub account, by the way I am Abdulkhaliq from Afghanistan , Herat .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue with that document is that it fails to mention that you will need to use a local Google Play services SDK for the time being until Google releases it out in the wild.

To get that, all you need to do is fill up the form in [this page](https://ahoy.twilio.com/verificationsdk) to get the SDK, and the in your code you will do the following:

1. Open `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`
2. add `PARTNER_SDK_DIR=/Users/{USER_NAME}/workspace/partner-sdk`
3. Import the SDK

So you should end up with somthing that looks like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url PARTNER_SDK_DIR
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

We have a sample application on our github repository which you can download and test. You will find it [here](https://github.com/authy/verification-quickstart-android)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you @Marcos Placona, you really helped me, but how long it would take to send the SDK to my email?

Comment: Should be a matter of a couple of days, if not less. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Dear @Marcos Placona : I have already filled up the form twice, but I didn't receive any email which it includes an SDK yet, and I need to implement this SMS verification as soon as possible please help me, How could I get Twilio's SDK and implement in my real application?